# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 on Thinkpad - Keyboard and mouse hangs followed by ACPI Error

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, keyboard, mouse

I have a new Thinkpad with Windows 10 pre-installed on which I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 18.04 (dual boot) from a live USB. I successfully boot into ubuntu using the "Try Ubuntu" option in the live USB. The keyboard and mouse work for about 10 seconds. After that I can't use the keyboard or click using the mouse (I can still move the mouse pointer). I tried connecting a separate USB mouse, that didn't help either - with the external mouse, I can't even move the cursor. 
After a couple of minutes, the system crashes with the following error message:

```
[ 0.589075] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - TUID (20181213/dspkginit-440)
[ 11.522497] Couldn't get size 0x80000...0e
[ 11.908224] nouveau 0000:01:00.0 fifo: fault 00 [READ] at 0000...0 engine 1f [PHYSICAL] client 07 [GPC0/T1_2] reason 0d [REGION_VIOLATION] on channel -1 [0000...0 unknown]
[ 13.337322] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No caching mode page found
[ 13.337358] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

I still can't do anything with the keyboard or mouse. The only option now is to long press the power button to hard reboot the laptop.

I also tried the "Install Ubuntu" option, again after a couple of clicks on the wizard, I can't proceed because the mouse and the keyboard stop working.

Any ideas for troubleshooting this?